# how to check radio Button on activity load

Tags: java, android

I have taken a radio group in my layout and I want to check one of the radio button from that radio group by default when activity is initialised. The re is a condition on which any one of the radio button should be checked by default.the code for that is:

```
  if (preferencedPractices == null) {

            allRadioBtn.setSelected(true);
            System.out.println("preferences are null");

        } else {
            prefRadioBtn.setSelected(true);
            System.out.println("there are some preferences");

        }
```

Here if preferencedPractices  is null, I want allRadioBtn checked by default else i want prefRadioBtn checked bydefault. But due to some reason this is not working. None of the button is checked when activity is started. I have  to check any of the button..Please help.

Comment: `allRadioBtn.setSelected(true);` Use this line after getting ids of all radio buttons.

Comment: I tried to do that. but then some other problem are occuring.As I have to display two sets of strings in spinner. which set to be displayed when is decided by checking of radio button. by doing this outside if block, it is affecting spinner data.

Comment: Post some more code then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file you can always have a radio button as checked using:

```
android:checked="true"
```

In your java code you can do the same using:

```
rb1= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);

rb2  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);

rb1.setChecked(true);
```

Just keep in mind that this will not work alone in `RadioGroup` you have to individually initialize the radiobutton which you want to set as checked.